# Mapping swift enum with associated values

Tags: arrays, swift, enums

Let say we have an enum with associated value types. In the example below the two value types are simple object that hold an image and a url to  share.

```
enum Content {
  case Image(ShareableImage)
  case Video(ShareableVideo)
}
```

Now let's have an array of video and image cases.

```
let media: [Content] = [*a lot of enum cases inside here*]
```

All the code above so far cannot be changed in any way in the codebase, I need to work with it.

---

**Here starts my problem:**

Let's filter the array with media to only image cases

```
    let imageOnlyCases: [Content] = media.filter { item -> Bool in

        switch item {
        case .Image: return true
        default: return false
        }
    }
```

Next step, I want to get from array of enum to an array of their associated values

```
[Content] -> [ShareableImage] by using map.
```

so I do this

```
    let shareablemages = imageOnlyCases.map { imageCase -> ShareableImage in

        switch imageCase {

        case .Image(let image): return image
        default: return  WHAT TO DO HERE?
        }
    }
```

You see, I have a problem with return type..I know that the enum cases are all .Image..and I want a simple map. But the swift syntax is not helping me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would return nil so you have an array of optionals associated values after that you can filter it to ged rid of nil.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could return `image` for case `.Image`, and `nil` otherwise, within a `.flatMap` operation (to "filter" out `nil` entries):

```
/* Example */
enum Foo {
    case Bar(Int)
    case Baz(Int)
}

let foo: [Foo] = [.Bar(1), .Bar(9),. Baz(3), .Bar(39), .Baz(5)]

/* 1. using 'switch' */
let barOnlyValues: [Int] = foo.flatMap {
    switch $0 {
    case .Bar(let val): return val
    case _: return nil
    }}

/* 2. alternatively, as pointed out in MartinR:s answer; 
      as you're only looking for a single case, the alternative
      'if case let' clause could be preferred over 'switch':     */
let barOnlyValuesAlt: [Int] = foo.flatMap {
    if case let .Bar(val) = $0 { return val }
    else { return nil }}                               

print(barOnlyValues) // [1, 9, 39]
```

Applied to your use case: note that you needn't perform the filtering to create the `imageOnlyCases` array, as you can apply the above directly on the `media` array:

```
/* 1. using switch */
let shareableImages : [ShareableImage] = media.flatMap {
    switch $0 {
    case .Image(let image): return image
    case _: return nil
    }}

/* 2. 'if case let' alternative, as per MartinR:s suggestion */
let shareableImagesAlt : [ShareableImage] = media.flatMap {
    if case let .Image(image) = $0 { return image }
    else { return nil }}
```

Disclaimer: I cannot verify your specific use case in practice as I don't have access to the `ShareableImage` class/struct.

(Thanks @MartinR for advice that `.map{ ... }.flatMap{ ... }` can be simplified to just `.flatMap{ ... }`).

Comment: Now you were faster :) – Simpler: `media.flatMap { ... }` instead of separate map() and flatMap calls.

Comment: Anyone else thinks `if case let .Image(let image) = value { ... }` is very weird looking? I just don't get this syntax. Swift book has only one example of this, and that's for unwrapping optional.

Comment: @nekonari the example in the language guide ([patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html)) does indeed cover accessing the wrapped value of an optional, but this is just one example of pattern matching against `enum` cases combined with binding to the associated value(s) in case the pattern matching succeeds. In this context, `Optional<Wrapped>` is just like any generic `enum`, making use of the generic type in some (or several) associated values for cases of the `enum`. Compare w. `switch` over `enum` cases.

Comment: @dfri Oh, I know what you mean. But if all you want is to grab the associated value in an `enum`, this pattern seems really awkward.

Comment: @nekonari I believe they've chosen to keep the same pattern for `if case let ...` as for when using a `switch` statement to bind associated values for different cases. I can agree that the look over the former takes some time getting used to, whereas for the latter (switching) the pattern matching feels natural. In the end, the choice of consistency here (with the possible "cost" of some exoticness), imo, is a good one.

Comment: You might want to update this answer with `compactMap`

Answer (score 2):

If it is *guaranteed* that only the `.Image` case can occur then
you can call `fatalError()` in all other cases:

```
let shareableImages = imageOnlyCases.map { imageCase -> ShareableImage in

    if case let .Image(image) = imageCase {
        return image
    } else {
        fatalError("Unexpected content")
    }
}
```

`fatalError()` causes the program to terminate immediately. It is
only meant for situations that "cannot occur", i.e. to find *programming
errors.*

It satisfies the compiler because the function is marked as `@noreturn`.

If you cannot make that guarantee then use `flatMap()` as suggested
in the other answer.

Note also that you can use `if case` here with a pattern instead
of `switch/case`.