# How to get index of enum case in array

Tags: swift, enums

I need to update associated value of `Enum` stored in an `Array`. How can I access the cell of the proper case without knowing its index?

```
enum MessageCell {
    case from(String)
    case to(String)
    case subject(String)
    case body(String)
}

var cells = [MessageCell.from(""), MessageCell.to(""), MessageCell.subject(""), MessageCell.body("")]

let recipient = "John"

// Hardcoded element position, avoid this
cells[1] = .to(recipient)

// How to find the index of .to case
if let index = cells.index(where: ({ ... }) {
    cells[index] = .to(recipient)
}
```

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651038/mapping-swift-enum-with-associated-values

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `if case` to test for the `enum` case `.to` in the closure and return `true` if found, otherwise return `false`:

```
if let index = cells.index(where: { if case .to = $0 { return true }; return false }) {
    cells[index] = .to(recipient)
}
```

---

Here's a complete example:

```
enum MessageCell {
    case from(String)
    case to(String)
    case subject(String)
    case body(String)
}

var cells: [MessageCell] = [.from(""), .to(""), .subject(""), .body("")]

if let index = cells.index(where: { if case .to = $0 { return true }; return false }) {
    print(".to found at index \(index)")
}
```

Output:

> ```
> .to found at index 1
> ```

Comment: It sucks that the closure has to be this convoluted; cf [SR-4644](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4644).

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to using `index(where:)`, you could use pattern matching with a `for` loop instead in order to iterate over the indices of the elements that match the given case, then simply `break` on the first match:

```
var cells: [MessageCell] = [.from(""), .to(""), .subject(""), .to("")]

let recipient = "John"

for case let (offset, .to) in cells.enumerated() {
    cells[offset] = .to(recipient)
    break
}

print(cells) 
// [MessageCell.from(""), MessageCell.to("John"),
//  MessageCell.subject(""), MessageCell.to("")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified demo of how you can solve this so that you get the idea of how this works:

```
var arr = ["a", "b"] // a, b
if let index = arr.index(where: { $0 == "a" }) {
    arr[index] = "c"
}
print(arr) // c, b
```

In your case:

```
if let index = cells.index(where: { if case .to = $0 { return true } else { return false } }) {
    cells[index] = .to(recipient)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if let index = cells.index(where: { (messageCell) -> Bool in
            switch messageCell
            {
            case .to(let x):
                return x == recipient ? true : false
            default:
                return false
            }
        })
        {
            cells[index] = .to(recipient)
        }
```